# C# XPathNavigator returns string of all values instead of values

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have XML document which is something like

```
<X><Y><Values><double>1.0</double><double>2.0</double></Values>...
```

I am trying to get those values:

```
toXpath.MoveToRoot(); // the X node name could be different
toXpath.MoveToFirstChild(); // this should be Y

string q = "Y/Values";
foreach (XPathNavigator x in toXpath.Select(q))
```

In x.Value I get something like "1.02.0"

Comment: It is indeed returning the values, but it's putting both values into x. Haven't used xpath in C# so I'm not sure what you need to do.

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: I bet the same thing happens with a VB.NET program, which would make this the .NET XPathNavigator, not the C# XPathNavigator.

Comment: john i know everything you can say in advance. dont bother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Y/Values
> ```

**selects a single element named `Values`** and child of the element `Y` that is a child of the top element `X`.

> ```
> string q = "Y/Values";       
> foreach (XPathNavigator x in toXpath.Select(q))
> ```

Because the XPath expression selects just a single node, you don't need a `foreach`...

> ```
> In x.Value I get something like "1.02.0"
> ```

**This is exactly what you should get**. The value of a node is the concatenation of all of its text-node descendents.

Most probably you want:

```
Y/Values/double
```

Comment: "Because the XPath expression selects just a single node, you don't need a foreach..." - how do I iterate through all children of a selected node?

Comment: @Bobb: You append to the expression that selects this node `/*` and this will select all element-children of the node. :)